# Timing release mode (optimized) functions

Tags: c, performance, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

I would like to do some benchmarking on a few simple functions in C.

```
// Record start time

  // Do a bunch of work
  for (int i = 0; i < SOME_BIG_NUMBER; i++)
    mySimpleFunction();

// Record stop time
```

In my release build configuration the compiler is smart enough to optimize this away.

Is there a canonical method of working with release configurations where you want optimizations enabled but still would like to force specific code to be executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the result:

```
int accum = 0;

// Record start time

  // Do a bunch of work
  for (int i = 0; i < SOME_BIG_NUMBER; i++)
    accum += mySimpleFunction();

// Record stop time

printf("%d", accum);
```